# Lagrangian of a system of 2 rods

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image: m]

For the above question I have proceeded in following way:

[image]

However I am unable to proceed and am unable to use $\theta$ in any further equation. I think I am getting the concept wrong somewhere.

For the second part I have proceeded in the following way:
Is the approach correct?

[image]

Comment: Are the rods free to pivot around $A$? So the configuration space is formed by $x_G,y_G, \theta,\phi$ ?

Comment: Yes the generalised coordinates would be $\ x_G,y_G, \theta,\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the kinetic energy calculation.
Calling

$$
\cases{
p_g = (\xi, \eta)\\
\vec n = (\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)\\
p_1 = p_g+a\sin\phi\vec n\\
p_2 = p_g-a\sin\phi\vec n\\
}
$$

Decomposing the kinetic energy into rotational plus translational  we have

$$
T = \frac 12 L\left((\dot \theta+\dot \phi)^2+(\dot \theta-\dot\phi)^2\right)+\frac m2 \dot p_1^2 + \frac m2 \dot p_2^2
$$

Here $L = \frac {1}{12}m(2a)^2$ and $p_1,p_2$ are the mass center for the two rods respectively.

$$
T = m \left(\dot \xi^2+\dot\eta^2+a^2 \left(\cos ^2(\phi)+\frac{1}{3}\right) \dot\phi^2+a^2 \left(\sin ^2(\phi)+\frac{1}{3}\right) \dot\theta^2\right)
$$

Comment: Is the angle AED = $\theta$ ? If yes, Why?

Comment: Note that the $\theta$ direction can be represented by the unit vector $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $\vec n = (\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)$ is also an unit vector orthogonal to the $\theta $ direction as needed to locate from $(\xi,\eta)$ the points $D, E$

Comment: But shouldn't $\vec n = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$  if $\vec n$ is from  P towards D ?

Comment: Due to the symmetry of $D,E$ regarding $(\xi,\eta)$ it doesn't matter.